# How to link a Radio Button choice to a taxonomy term or tag

Tags: taxonomy-terms

Using drupal 7, when my users select a certain choice out of 2 radio buttons, i want whichever one they choose to also have a tag or taxonomy term applied to it. So if they chose "never" then that node will also have the tag "never"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by creating a term reference field for your **content type**(structure ­> content types > your content type > manage fields) or **users**(configuration > people > account settings > manage fields). Just pick radio/checkboxes widget with only 1 value.

Comment: I tried creating a term reference field, but it instead just listed the available tags instead of converting the radio button term to a tag.

Comment: the term reference will list the terms in the chosen vocabulary, it's how it works :)

Comment: it's really important that you use the **radio/check boxes widget**.

Comment: ha gotcha well i guess then it worked like you said! However that still doesnt solve my initial problem. I want whichever radio button choice chosen, to also tag that node with the same term. So if they choose never, then the node will be tagged never subsequently

Comment: Is the field in content type or people right now? What kind of node are your users creating? The solution would be to add a "never" term in your vocabulary. Then your node will be tagged with that term.

Comment: it is in content type right now, i want the node to be tagged with whatever choice they choose using the radio buttons, essentially im forcing them to pick between 2 tags, and later then can add custom tags in the same node

Comment: Then just add the tags as terms in your vocabulary. Whenever you add new tags, they will be available as new radio buttons. Hope that helps!

Comment: See this link for **creating a vocabulary** : http://drupal.org/node/23405 and this link for **using term reference field** : http://drupalize.me/videos/categorizing-content-term-reference-field

Comment: davidgmar, thank you, it was all so simple! issue resolved

Comment: davidgmar, thank you, it was all so simple! issue resolved

Comment: You're welcome. [You should accept this answer by clicking the hollow check](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

One one you could do this is have the node automatically updated immediately after or before being saved, by using Rules.

You can have a rule set up to check the value of that particular field (with the 2 radio buttons) and depending on the value, or if the field is empty, set up the rule to "Add a value to a list" where the list corresponds to a field on that node enabled for taxonomy terms.

Comment: installed rules and entity, if you could jus tpoint me to where I would need to apply the rule set i could figure it out, hopefully